# Do you need validators for a demographic profile questionnaire?

Tags: survey, scales, scale-construction

I am conducting a thesis and I created a survey questionnaire that would help to answer the questions in my statement of the problem.

Now, I am wondering if the questionnaire I created is already good to distribute to the target respondents or shall I need to find validators to validate my questionnaire?

My questionnaire doesn't include likert scales and is pure questions about their demographic profile (like their sex, age, current location they are living in).

I hope someone could enlighten me about this.

Comment: To whoever downvote my question, could you give me the reason why did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a good idea to conduct a pilot survey before distributing the survey to a larger group of people, even if the questions look simple and straightforward *to you*.

Feedback from pilot respondents allows identifying questions that may be unclear to some people, identifying options that should be included in the survey but that you forgot, or questions that are interpreted very differently by different respondents.

Problems or inconsistencies in your questions inevitably happen when you've been spending some time designing a survey and lack hindsight on your work - so an external review is rarely a bad idea.

For instance, an apparently simple question like "How old are you?" is ambiguous. Are you asking about the birth year, or about the age?

If you ask a question about gender, do you leave an option available for people who do not want to choose "man" or "woman"? Depending on the population you're surveying, should it be an open-ended question, or a close-ended question?

If you ask "Where do you live currently?", it may be ambiguous or difficult to answer for people about to move elsewhere, for people who do not have a fixed address, for seasonal workers, for long-stay tourists (or even for some short-stay tourists, as "living somewhere" may be interpreted differently by different people), etc.

Some feedback from a part of your population of interest may be valuable to identify possible problems like that, before distributing your survey more widely.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that validators are needed in this case. As far as I know, questions with likert scales are the ones that needed validators.